# CSV prints blank column between each data column

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

So, the title explains my question - please see the image for clarification.

[image]

I have tried the fixes from a couple of questions on here to no avail, so here is my code:

```
def csv_writer(file_a, file_b):
    with open('Comparison.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', escapechar=' ', lineterminator='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        line = map(compare, file_a.master_list, file_b.master_list)
        for line in line:
            if line != None:
                writer.writerow(line)
            else:
                del line
```

The data for `line` on line 6 is a list in the following format:
`['20,', 'start,', '1000,', '1002']`.

I assume that my issue is to do with `escapechar=' '`, but having tried a variety of different options with no success I'm at a loss.

Comment: Have you tried opening the CSV file in a text editor rather than Excel? Does this produce the same issue?

Comment: If you have commas in your data and use `QUOTE_NONE` they will get interpreted as delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what is happening is that you are getting two `,` characters between each data item.

For example, in `['20,', 'start,', '1000,', '1002']`, each element is joined with a `,` because of the `delimiter=','` option. This means that the `,` is being repeated and you'll end up with:

```
20,,start,,1000,,1002
```

Notice how there is an empty item between each of the items you want.

You can probably fix this by replacing `delimiter=','` with `delimiter=''` as you already have the `,` character and don't need another one.

Hope this helps!